# How does the Python subprocess module find executables to run? Can I change the location?

Tags: python, subprocess

On Linux systems, `subprocess.run(["some_command"])` appears to scrape `/usr/bin` for `some_command` by default and thus, *subprocess* accepts every command that also has a respective binary in this directory.

I have a use case now, where I have binaries in multiple directories and I want to execute some of them with the *subprocess* module. Obviously, I can do something like:

```
subprocess.run(["/absolute/path/to/first_binary"])
subprocess.run(["/another/absolute/path/to/another/second_binary"])
```

But I was wondering if there exists anything like:

```
subprocess.set_bin_dirs(["/usr/bin/", "/absolute/path/to/", "/another/absolute/path/to/another/"]) 
subprocess.run(["first_binary"]) 
subprocess.run(["second_binary"])
```

Comment: It uses the `PATH` environment variable, just like executing commands from the shell.

Comment: This has *nothing to do with Python and the `subprocess` module*. This is a core idea about how Unix-like(and other) operating systems work, when you do `some_command`, that command is looked up *on your `PATH`*. So you must add that directories of these binaries to the PATH, otherwise, you need to use the ful path when you do a command, e.g. `/usr/bin/some_command`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga This makes sense. If you post a separate answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @c0mr4t I posted it as community wiki... you and others should feel free to elaborate on it, I actually suspect this question might receive a lot of hits on search engines.

Comment: ...re: "how UNIX-like operating systems work" -- note that the `execve()` syscall expects path lookup to already be complete, so it's not quite so low-level as to be built into the kernel; on the other hand, the standard C library provides wrappers like `execvp()` that do a lookup in the PATH and only afterwards call another `execv*`-family function. The same is true with more modern analogues `posix_spawn()` and `posix_spawnp()` -- there's a lower-level call that expects an absolute path and a higher-level one that does a PATH lookup first.

Comment: (to provide context to the above comment: "syscalls" are how the operating system kernel is asked to do something by an application; so every time Python or anything else wants to open a file or network connection, do a read, a write, etc., that involves a syscall; those standard C library functions that need the operating system's help to do something invoke syscalls, potentially adding error handling / better standards compliance / etc on top).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Python and the `subprocess` module. This is a core idea about how Unix-like(and other) operating systems work, when you do `some_command`, that command is looked up on your `PATH`. So you must add that directories of these binaries to the PATH, otherwise, you need to use the full path when you try to execute a command, e.g. `/usr/bin/some_command`

To do this in Python with the `subprocess` module, you could do something like:

```
import os
env_copy = os.environ.copy()
current_path = current_env['PATH']

env_copy["PATH"] = os.pathsep.join([
    "/usr/bin/", 
    "/absolute/path/to/", 
    "/another/absolute/path/to/another/", 
    current_path
])

subprocess.run(["some_command"], env=env_copy)
```

Note, paths are looked up in order, so the order in which you append it matters if there are possible name-collisions. Note, you don't actually have to add the current PATH, but you might. All of this is up to you.